# Zend PHP Uploaded File Permission on Windows 7

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload, file-permissions

I have Zend Server CE running on Windows 7. By Default I have Apache running as a Service, Log On as Local System Account.

My upload Action saves an uploaded file to its Destination OK, however the permission on the file is set to only SYSTEM, Administrators and IIS_IUSERS.

Once uploaded, I cannot open it or move it using PHP. I am using the following code to receive the file in Zend Framework on POST:

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();

$upload->setDestination($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/".$upFolder);

if (!$upload->isValid()) {
     $messages = $upload->getMessages();
         throw new Exception( implode("\n", $messages));
     }else{
         try {
             $upload->receive();
      }
      catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e)
      {
          throw new Exception('Bad file: '.$e->getMessage());
      }
```

How can I set permissions so that I can use the uploaded file in php/zend

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I can actually move it, however I can not open the file. It is an csv file. when i right click->properties->Security it says "To Continue, you must be an administrative user with permission to view this object's security properties"

What I am actually trying to do is call a proceedure from php on this file, see above.

Comment: Did you resolve this?  Sounds likes UAC to me, just turn that feature off ...

Answer (score 0):

Despite the suggestion of some, turning UAC off is not the answer. This kind of issue is typically caused by your Zend Server setup, not UAC per se.  Check the parent directory permissions (ownership, read/write permissions, etc.), as the permissions are often set to be inherited by any child files/folders.

**If you can't resolve this dilemma via adjustments to permissions:**

Have you tried a fresh install of Zend Server?  First, I would try installing Zend Server *without* running "as administrator?"  (I never run Zend Server as admin. during installation, and haven't had any issues to date.)

Comment: This is most likely the problem, but I no longer have that project to test :( thx though.